# How can i include two textboxes in Ext.Msg.show

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

How can I modify the Ext.Msg.show in sencha to show two text boxes.Right now it supports only one textbox when we set prompt:true

```
Ext.Msg.show({
    title: 'Enter values',
    width: 500,
    buttons: Ext.Msg.OKCANCEL,
    multiline: true,
    prompt:true,
});
```

Answer (score 7):

The easiest solution is just create a window. Like Evan said in the comment, the MessageBox is just an `Ext.window.Window` width a little extra..

a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/9xTNY/1/)

Here's a example definition:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    height: 220,
    width: 490,
    layout: 'fit',
    modal: true,
    buttonAlign: 'left',
    closable: false,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'form',
            frame: false,
            border: 0,
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'middle'
            },
            fieldDefaults: {
                msgTarget: 'side',
                labelWidth: 55
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    flex: 1,
                    padding: 10,
                    layout: {
                        type: 'vbox',
                        align: 'stretch'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name: 'username',
                            fieldLabel: 'Username',
                            allowBlank: false,
                            flex: 1
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name: 'password',
                            fieldLabel: 'Password',
                            inputType: 'password',
                            allowBlank: false,
                            flex: 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Login',
            handler: function () {
                Ext.Msg.alert('This is not yet implemented.').show();
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Then you can just create and show the window:

```
Ext.create('MyApp.view.Login').show();
```

Comment: +1, the messagebox is just a `Ext.window.Window` with some custom items.

Comment: This is the prefered way to go.

Comment: Great answer. To close the window when the button is clicked, use `this.up('window').close();` in the button handler.

Comment: How to get the values of the inputs in the button handler?

Answer (score 4):

The msg property of the Ext.MessageBox will render as HTML, so you can tell it to show two HTML inputs and then use the values from these using something like

```
Ext.Msg.show(
{
    title: 'Enter values:',
    width: 500,
    buttons: Ext.Msg.OKCANCEL,
    msg: 'Value1: <input type="text" id="textInput1" /><br />Value 2: <input type="text" id="textInput2" />',
    fn: function (button)
    {
        var value1 = document.getElementById('textInput1').value;
        var value2 = document.getElementById('textInput2').value;
    }
});
```

Although, depending on what you're trying to do, using a window as suggested may be a better solution

Comment: getting the elements by id like that is not really flexible.. As you can have only 1 message box like this on your page. Id's should be unique on a page.

Comment: @dkwarr87: Thanks for the solution.It was a quick fix and helped me get two text boxes

Comment: @VDP : Appreciate your answer as well though I have not implemented it :)